# How to apply a function to a metadata value before launch a WP Query?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I have these WP_Query arguments:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'         =>  'my_post_type',
   'order'     =>   'ASC',
   'meta_key'   =>  'date',
   'orderby'   =>  'meta_value_num'
```

);

And I use `get_posts()` to call a new WP_Query($args):

```
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Now,`date` is saved in DB like ie `2018-05-30 21:15:00`.

So, I would apply a function like `strtotime('meta_value')`to convert the value in Epoch time **before** WP_Query is called and - **after** - the posts would be filtered by Epoch time value and not by string.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run arbitrary PHP functions in a query like that. `WP_Query` (which `get_posts()` uses) doesn't retrieve posts then filter them with PHP, it gets turned into an SQL query which finds the results.

The proper way to order `meta_value` by date in SQL would be to cast it as `DATETIME`. The way `WP_Query` allows you to do this is by the `meta_type` argument. From [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters):

> You may also specify `‘meta_type‘` if you want to cast the meta value as
>   a specific type. Possible values are ‘NUMERIC’, ‘BINARY’, ‘CHAR’,
>   ‘DATE’, ‘DATETIME’, ‘DECIMAL’, ‘SIGNED’, ‘TIME’, ‘UNSIGNED’, same as
>   in `‘$meta_query‘`.

In your case you'd use it like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'meta_key'  => 'date',
    'meta_type' => 'DATETIME',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value'
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);
```

Note that I haven't tested this, as I don't have appropriate data to test with.

Comment: It works! Thanks! So, under no circumstances you can run PHP functions on WP_Query arguments? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really know how to answer that, because the question doesn't really make sense. It depends what you want to do. Maybe start with [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) to see what you can do.